# How to update a custom object through trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

This is the scenario.

I have 2 custom object. Such CustomobjA__C and search__c. Here search__c is a lookup to CustomobjA__C

When page loads 29 records will get inserted(CustomobjA__C ) and 1 search record will get inserted which will default as true.

If I added a new search which will again create 29 records(CustomobjA__C ) and this search should be the default search. So I want the previous 29 records to changed to false and new 29 should be true.

Here is the code i am using

```
search__c objSearch = new search__c(
            Search_Name__c = searchName, 
            user__c  = userId,
            Default__c= true
        );
        INSERT objSearch; 
       
        if(objSearch.id != null){
            userColumnPrefs = [Select Id, Field_API_Name__c,search__r.Default__c,RefreshJson__c,,Primary_Sort__c,
                           search__c,Default_Order__c, Primary_Sort_Ascending__c
                           FROM CustomobjA__C 
                           WHERE UserId__c = :userId 
                           AND search__r.Default__c =true];
        }
        
        for(CustomobjA__C objuserPref:userColumnPrefs){
            
            CustomobjA__C newuserPref = new CustomobjA__C (
            
                Default_Order__c = objuserPref.Default_Order__c,
                Field_API_Name__c = objuserPref.Field_API_Name__c,
                Primary_Sort__c = objuserPref.Primary_Sort__c,
                Primary_Sort_Ascending__c = objuserPref.Primary_Sort_Ascending__c,
                RefreshJson__c = objuserPref.RefreshJson__c,
               search__c = objSearch.Search_Name__c
            
            );
            newsearchtoInsert.add(newuserPref);t
        }
       
        INSERT newsearchtoInsert;
```

HERE is the code I am using in trigger

```
trigger SmartDashGridSavedSearch on search__c (before update, after update, before insert, after insert) {
Map<Id,search__c > idBySmartDashGridSavedSearch = new Map<Id,search__c >([select id,Default__c,Search_Name__c from search__c ]);
List<search__c > addtoUpdate = new List<search__c >();
List<CustomobjA__C> userptoUpdate = new List<CustomobjA__C>();

if(trigger.isbefore){
    if(trigger.isInsert){
        for(SmartDashGrid_Saved_Search__c obj:idBySmartDashGridSavedSearch.values()){
            obj.Default__c= false;
            addtoUpdate.add(obj);
        }
    
    }
    
    
}

if(trigger.isAfter){
    if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        for(search__c obj: [select id,Default__c,Search_Name__c from search__c 
                                                WHERE ID 
                                                NOT IN:trigger.new AND Default__c=true ]){
                                                    obj.Default__c = false;
                                                    addtoUpdate.add(obj);
                                                }
        
       
    }
}
 UPDATE addtoUpdate;}
```

I tried almost a day on this to update. Please help to get through this.

Comment: It seems that you don't doing update in second part of the trigger. You have UPDATE addToUpdate only before entering this section

Comment: It seems a little overengineered here. From what you say, when a new `search__c` record is inserted, the one existing record which has `Default__c` = true needs to be set to false instead, and the newly inserted one should have `Default__c` = true. Is that right?

Comment: Yes exactly. default__C is field in search__c which is a lookUp to customObj,So if i add new search it should be default as true and existing one as false and its related customObj as well.What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: no error.it is not working as expected

Comment: It is not updating